# Cpanel node js host problem It says expected ( saw {. need fixes please

Tags: node.js, deployment, cpanel

I am having problem while hosting my **nodejs** app in cPanel. It says expected ( saw {. any fixes? The first route/api is working but when we go to /api/user it wont work. Is there any way I can fix this?

[Error in async await](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQDtr.png)

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT;

const { User, Home } = require("./models")


const cors = require("cors");


app.use(express.json())

const { sequelize } = require("./models")

async function main() {
    await sequelize.sync({});
}

// main();

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "*",
    })
);
app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        "message": "API enpoints for first app"
    });
});

const userRouter = require("./routes/user");
const homeRouter = require("./routes/home");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// app.use("/user", userRouter);
app.use("/home", homeRouter);

app.get("/api/user", async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.findAll(
        {
            include: [
                {
                    model: Home, as: "homes",
                },
            ]
        }

    );

    res.json({
        "message": "success",
        "data": users
    });
});
app.get('/api/node-version', (req, res) => {
  res.send(process.version);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("yo yo let's goo");
});
```

The node version i am using is 18.15.0 and works perfectly on localhost. The node versions available in cpanel are <16.20.1 and 18.16.0.